# GitLab not showing merge commit as latest commit in repository view

Tags: gitlab

The master branch of some repository shows the following:

```
git log --pretty=oneline
aa188d43bb15281404d0a616d49127c1d3895ae6 Add README feature
d00acc681100324f3df321e5695e123804674d77 Elaborate
f6cc0612c7c0d17f79524a10931d4727918dd43b Improve example
c847a83c9db38f06b1c1897ba121537446edac34 Initial commit
```

The latest commit is a merge. It shows up as the latest commit in the [commits/master](https://gitlab.com/gustavo.goretkin/howtogitlab/commits/master) of gitlab.

However, it doesn't show up as the latest commit in [tree/master](https://gitlab.com/gustavo.goretkin/howtogitlab/tree/master) . A screenshot:[image].

Is there a configuration for this somewhere? Why not show the merge commit on top?

Comment: Are you running your own instance? Maybe this was caused by a background task (Sidekiq job) that was killed.

Comment: this is on gitlab.com I included links to the repository in my question.